# Can't get dropotron script to work properly [HTML/CSS/JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I asked a previous question about creating a dropdown menu on my webpage similar to a template. I figured out that the template was using dropotron to create this menu. I downloaded dropotron and attempted to follow the instructions it provided.

[Here's my website](http://zachdamit.cechire.com/five), and [here's the example that shows a working dropotron script](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Multi-level-Dropdown-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-dropotron/).

Here's a codepen link to the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript: codepen.io/anon/pen/EPaYNz

What's odd is that it works in codepen result, but I'm not sure why it's buggy on my site. I copied the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files exactly.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** another misc bug I found on the codepen result was when I hover over "Biography" in the submenu, "Who I Am" disappears. Any way to fix this, too?

Comment: You're getting an error on your website: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropotron is not a function`. Meaning the `dropotron()` method wasn't added to jQuery yet. When I type `$.dropotron` in your website it comes back `undefined` but on the example page it comes back with the function. So at some point, `dropotron` isn't actually being created.

Comment: It might be that jQuery `script` tag in your `head` element. Add `http:` before the `//` and that might work.

Comment: Added, but it didn't change anything. I'm pretty lost when it comes to javascript, so I'm not too sure what I should be looking to change based on your first answer. Any other guesses as to what it might be?

Comment: I'd also like to point out that you're requesting jQuery in your `head` element and also at the end of your `body` element. You only need one. Maybe remove the one in the `head` element and move the `dropotron` `script` tag down right above your `main.js` `script` tag.

Comment: Also make sure that `script` with the code stays below the `dropotron` script tag.

Comment: Fixed. I moved both `<script src>` tags that were in the `head` element with the others at the `body` element. Left the `<script> $(function() {` tag where it's at. Still no change.

Comment: So it's working now? If so, I'll write it up as an answer so you can call this question answered.

Comment: Nope, still looks the same as it did before.

Comment: You said you didn't move the `<script> $(function(){` tag? That needs to be BELOW the `dropotron` script tag.

Comment: Moved it, but it still looks the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formatting purposes I'm putting this as an answer. Your scripts should look like this at the bottom and there should be no scripts in the `head`:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {

    // Note: make sure you call dropotron on the top level <ul>
    $('#nav > ul').dropotron({ 
      offsetY: -10 // Nudge up submenus by 10px to account for padding
    });

  });
</script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

*By the way, your `<--[if lte blah]` didn't have the closing angle bracket `>` all the way at the end*

Comment: This worked! Ironically, it no longer works on codepen when I copy the changes over. Thank you so much for your help! Seemed like a real easy fix <_<
Any way to keep "Who I Am" from disappearing when hovering over items in the submenu? Changes are live [on the site](http://zachdamit.cechire.com/five)

Comment: Possibly in your CSS. It looks like under `#nav ul li.active a` you set the color to white (`#FFFFFF`). Just remove the color line.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help. I know some of my issues were pretty trivial. Thanks a bunch!