# Dropdown symbol doesn't appear in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, skel

I'm currently struggling with my select box.

For some reason the "arrow-down" symbol doesn't appear when I use the chrome browser... So on IE and Firefox it is working fine.

**How it looks in Chrome?**

[image: Chrome]

**How it should look? (e.g. Firefox)**

[image]

**Any error messages?**

Yeah, I don't know why, but I receive following error message **on every browser**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropotron is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (init.js:76)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

**The affected Code**

```
// Dropdowns.
        $('#nav > ul').dropotron({
            mode: 'fade',
            noOpenerFade: true,
            alignment: 'center',
            detach: false
        });
```

**What Framework(s) / Labrarie(s) am I using ?**

I'm just using jQuery and skel... maybe there is a complication there ?

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong...? I can't find any solution nowhere.

Comment: I think you have to change dropotron to dropdown

Comment: @saumil_jariwala no, it just changed the error message... now obviously it says "...dropdown is not a function"

Comment: Please look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125427/cant-get-dropotron-script-to-work-properly-html-css-javascript

Comment: @saumil_jariwala that's not my problem. My dropdown is working... just de symbol doesn' appear. In addition, i definately importet de js files right.